# Distance of lines : Shouldn't it be $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

We are given the lines \begin{equation*}g: \ \vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}+s\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\0 \end{pmatrix} \, \ , \, \ h: \ \vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}9 \\ -8 \\6 \end{pmatrix}+t\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\2 \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} I want to calcuate the distance.

$$$$

Let $G$, $H$ be points on the lines $g$ and $h$ respectively.

Then these will be of the form \begin{equation*}G=\begin{pmatrix}s \\ -1-s \\1 \end{pmatrix} \ , \ H=\begin{pmatrix}9 +2t\\ -8-3t \\6+2t \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} 
So we get \begin{equation*}\vec{GH}=\begin{pmatrix}9 +2t\\ -8-3t \\6+2t \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}s \\ -1-s \\1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}9 +2t-s\\ -7-3t+s \\5+2t \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

We choose the points $G$ and $H$ such that $\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}=0$ and $\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\2 \end{pmatrix}=0$.

We have the following: 
\begin{equation*}\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}=0\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}9 +2t-s\\ -7-3t+s \\5+2t \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}=0  \Rightarrow 16 +5t-2s=0\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\2 \end{pmatrix}=0\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}9 +2t-s\\ -7-3t+s \\5+2t \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\2 \end{pmatrix}=0 \Rightarrow 49+17t-5s=0
\end{equation*}

Solving the system 
\begin{align*}&16 +5t-2s=0  \\  &49+17t-5s=0\end{align*} we get $t=-2, \ s=3$.

Now we can calculate the vector $\vec{GH}$: 
\begin{equation*}\vec{GH}=\begin{pmatrix}9 +2\cdot (-2)-3\\ -7-3\cdot (-2)+3 \\5+2\cdot (-2) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 2 \\1 \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} 
The distance $|\vec{GH}|$ of the lines $g$ and $h$ is therefore equal to \begin{equation*}|\vec{GH}|=\sqrt{2^2+2^2+1^2}=\sqrt{4+4+1}=\sqrt{9}=3\end{equation*}

Is everything correct?

After that I made the graphs and I saw that these lines are intersecting. Shouldn't we get then  that the distance is equal to $0$ ?

Comment: Why do you think these lines intersect?  And if so, where?

Comment: How did you make a graph? These are lines in three dimensions, which are hard to draw on two-dimensional paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines do not intersect

[image]

Comment: Ahh! I used an online tool and I got the following graph: https://ibb.co/PF9N3vw So I must have done something wrong at that tool... But the way I calculated the diastance is correct, isn't it?

Comment: @MaryStar : Hold your arms out in front of you, crossed, so they look like your lines.  Notice that your arms don't actually pass through each other.  It's not enough to see this graph from one angle.
Also, I don't see anything wrong with your calculation.

Comment: Ahhh!! Now I found that we can move the graph :  https://www.matheretter.de/geoservant/de/?draw=gerade(0%7C-1%7C1%201%7C-2%7C1)+gerade(9%7C-8%7C6%2011%7C-11%7C8) Thanks for the clarifications!! :-)